# Puppeteer Extract Elements via XPath

Tags: javascript, node.js, xpath, puppeteer

I am trying to get elements within a div that doesn't have ID's that exist and classes that may change. Currently, trying to get more than one of the ID's but also the thumbnail on the main page, visit it and extract content

**Example Site Content:**

```
<div class="styles__StyledMomentsContainer-sc-17o5rr3-0 deifAl">
<div class="ThumbnailLayouts__ThumbnailGrid-sc-18xwycr-0 iCffwQ">

<a href="/item/9de94ac5">
<div class="Thumbnail__StyledThumbnail-sc-1tojpin-0 kAMKVp">
<div class="TextContainer__StyledTextContainer-qfpzkm-0 xDxPM MomentThumbnail__StyledTopTooltips-sc-1b051xk-6 MintedMomentThumbnail__StyledMomentDecorator-sc-15to4ef-0 lcjjoh cYwkaa">
<div class="WatchEditionButton__TooltipParent-sc-1lygyd7-1 cVhMzY">
<div class="Tooltip__Prompt-sc-1l5uqjy-3 gYgTGI">
<button type="button" data-attr="watchlistEditionButton" data-testid="watchlistEditionButton" class="ButtonBase__StyledButton-sc-1qgxh2e-0 gjCpfL Button__StyledButton-ig3kkl-1 cRYYjU WatchEditionButton__StyledWatchlistButton-sc-1lygyd7-0 jDAurt">
<span class="text">292</span>
</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="Image__StyledImageWrapper-jm0vhd-0 cvgQAN MomentThumbnail__StyledImage-sc-1b051xk-0 hcGMXV">
<img src="https://website/assetfile.png" class="Image__StyledImage-jm0vhd-1 crAhYf thumbnail-img"></div>
<div class="TextContainer__StyledTextContainer-qfpzkm-0 xDxPM MomentThumbnail__StyledTextContainer-sc-1b051xk-3 ifzfmD">
<h3 class="Title__StyledTitle-vk55y-0 kUfGiv MomentThumbnail__StyledTitle-sc-1b051xk-4 eZtJpe"> Bob Walker</h3>
<p class="Description__StyledDescription-uunwk3-0 kinrOa MomentThumbnail__StyledDescription-sc-1b051xk-5 ddTMzZ">Layup - Nov 13 2021</p>
<h4 class="Subtitle__StyledSubtitle-sc-112br97-0 jNwNYO">
<span class="MomentThumbnail__StyledRarityTag-sc-1b051xk-8 ffAJvh">Common</span>
<span class="MomentThumbnail__StyledScarcityTag-sc-1b051xk-7 iXKcIn">#29672 / 60000<div class="Tooltip__Prompt-sc-1l5uqjy-3 gYgTGI">
<span class="TextBadge__Badge-ql1ilr-0 hXOPDq">LE</span>
</div>
</span>
</h4>
</div>
</div>
</a>

<a href="/item/85de94ac5">
<div class="Thumbnail__StyledThumbnail-sc-1tojpin-0 kAMKVp">
<div class="TextContainer__StyledTextContainer-qfpzkm-0 xDxPM MomentThumbnail__StyledTopTooltips-sc-1b051xk-6 MintedMomentThumbnail__StyledMomentDecorator-sc-15to4ef-0 lcjjoh cYwkaa">
<div class="WatchEditionButton__TooltipParent-sc-1lygyd7-1 cVhMzY">
<div class="Tooltip__Prompt-sc-1l5uqjy-3 gYgTGI">
<button type="button" data-attr="watchlistEditionButton" data-testid="watchlistEditionButton" class="ButtonBase__StyledButton-sc-1qgxh2e-0 gjCpfL Button__StyledButton-ig3kkl-1 cRYYjU WatchEditionButton__StyledWatchlistButton-sc-1lygyd7-0 jDAurt">
<span class="text">292</span>
</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="Image__StyledImageWrapper-jm0vhd-0 cvgQAN MomentThumbnail__StyledImage-sc-1b051xk-0 hcGMXV">
<img src="https://website/assetfileNew.png" class="Image__StyledImage-jm0vhd-1 crAhYf thumbnail-img"></div>
<div class="TextContainer__StyledTextContainer-qfpzkm-0 xDxPM MomentThumbnail__StyledTextContainer-sc-1b051xk-3 ifzfmD">
<h3 class="Title__StyledTitle-vk55y-0 kUfGiv MomentThumbnail__StyledTitle-sc-1b051xk-4 eZtJpe">Alexander-Walker</h3>
<p class="Description__StyledDescription-uunwk3-0 kinrOa MomentThumbnail__StyledDescription-sc-1b051xk-5 ddTMzZ">Layup - Nov 13 2021</p>
<h4 class="Subtitle__StyledSubtitle-sc-112br97-0 jNwNYO">
<span class="MomentThumbnail__StyledRarityTag-sc-1b051xk-8 ffAJvh">Common</span>
<span class="MomentThumbnail__StyledScarcityTag-sc-1b051xk-7 iXKcIn">#29672 / 60000<div class="Tooltip__Prompt-sc-1l5uqjy-3 gYgTGI">
<span class="TextBadge__Badge-ql1ilr-0 hXOPDq">LE</span>
</div>
</span>
</h4>
</div>
</div>
</a>

</div>
</div>
```

I am essentially using XPath as I don't have DIV ID's I can use. This is the code I am trying to use:

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
import * as fs from 'fs/promises';
var url = "https://URL";

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'], headless: false} );
const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.goto(url);

const assetUrls = await page.$$eval(
  '#__next > div.AppTemplate__Wrapper-d5brw1-1.kvEiEU > main > div.Tabs__StyledRoot-o4bemc-0.fFvYXn > div.Tabs__StyledTabContentWrapper-o4bemc-5.lbrCFS > div > div > div > div.FilterWrappersstyles__StyledFiltersAndMoments-sc-1819eu0-7.dXIUkn > div > div > div > div.ThumbnailLayouts__ThumbnailGrid-sc-18xwycr-0.iCffwQ',
  assetLinks => assetLinks.map(link => link.href)
);

const results = [];

// Visit each assets page one by one
for (let assetsUrl of assetUrls) {
  await page.goto(url);
    
  // Now collect all the ICO urls.
  const icoUrls = await page.$$eval(
    '#__next > div.AppTemplate__Wrapper-d5brw1-1.kvEiEU > main > div.Tabs__StyledRoot-o4bemc-0.fFvYXn > div.Tabs__StyledTabContentWrapper-o4bemc-5.lbrCFS > div > div > div > div.FilterWrappersstyles__StyledFiltersAndMoments-sc-1819eu0-7.dXIUkn > div > div > div > div.ThumbnailLayouts__ThumbnailGrid-sc-18xwycr-0.iCffwQ > a:nth-child(1)',
    links => links.map(link => link.href)
  );

  // Visit each ICO one by one and collect the data.
  for (let icoUrl of icoUrls) {
    await page.goto(icoUrl);

    const icoImgUrl = await page.$eval('source', source => source.src);
    const icoName = await page.$eval('h1', h1 => h1.innerText.trim());
    const icoDesc = await page.$eval('a', a => a.innerText.trim());
    // TODO: Gather all the needed info like description etc here.

    results.push([{
      icoUrl,
      icoImgUrl,
      icoName,
      icoDesc
    }]);
  }
}

// Results are ready
console.log(results);

browser.close();
```

Currently I do get:

```
[
  [
    {
      icoUrl: 'https://assets.com/url-to-item-to-scrape-from',
      icoImgUrl: 'https://assets.com/file.mp4',
      icoName: 'ALEXANDER-WALKER',
      icoDesc: ''
    }
  ]
]
```

I am trying to get:

- URL to each item...
- Serial ID# (MomentThumbnail__StyledScarcityTag-sc-1b051xk-7 iXKcIn) - #29672 / 60000
- Date (Description__StyledDescription-uunwk3-0 kinrOa MomentThumbnail__StyledDescription-sc-1b051xk-5 ddTMzZ - Layup - Nov 13 2021)
- Name (Title__StyledTitle-vk55y-0 kUfGiv MomentThumbnail__StyledTitle-sc-1b051xk-4 eZtJpe - Alexander-Walker)

Comment: Can you add some more detail to help answer, such as an error you are getting or what is not working with your code?

Comment: @treckstar, yup, I modified my post!